# Assign this to a method in typescript for intillisense

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider a method

```
function getName(){
   return this.name ;
}
```

now this method when called will have context of below class

```
class Person{
  name:string

  constructor(name){
     this.name=name;
  }
}

const person = new Person("Ujjwal");

getName.call(person);
```

the above implementation work but we don't get IntelliSense support or let's say I want to tightly couple the method with Person context.

Is there any way to achieve this?

NOTE: - I don't want to assign that `getName` method in class `Person`. `getName` will be always an independent method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised to learn a few weeks ago this totally works:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
}

function getName(this: Person) {
  return this.name;
}

const person : Person = {
  name: 'hi'
}

getName.bind(person);
```

It compiles to;

```js
"use strict";
function getName() {
    return this.name;
}
const person = {
    name: 'hi'
};
getName.bind(person);
```

And yes IDE's should support completion for this.

Comment: Of note: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Maybe if you provide more context there might be a better solution. For now, I guess, you can do something like this:

```
function getName<T extends NameInterface>(context:T):string{
   return context.name ;
}

interface NameInterface {
  name: string;
}

class Person implements NameInterface{
  name:string

  constructor(name: string){
     this.name=name;
  }
}

const person = new Person("Ujjwal");

let personName:string = getName(person);
console.log(personName);
```

Here I'm making your `getName()` function generic to be able to work with any object that has `name` property. To ensure type checking I introduced the `NameInterface`. Now any object that implements this interface can be passed into `getName()` function.

Comment: here you are passing context as parameter. My requirement is to be called using call or apply like -  ```getName.call(person)```.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use `call()`? What are you trying to accomplish with this approach?

Comment: i am working on a library but i don't want to define the method which are not necessary for user to define into class (not to confuse users), so i am keeping these method outside of the class.